# Multiple memcached with one infinispan?

Tags: configuration, memcached, infinispan

Infinispan understands the memcached protocol.

is it possible to expose multiple infinispan caches as memcached servers on different ports without actually starting multiple infinispan instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not seem to be possible at the moment and as I'm not that experienced with scala i can't make it work with code.

Answer (score 0):

No, one Memcached server per Infinispan CacheManager/Cache instance. Starting multiple Infinispan instances should be easy though, any problems with that?